# Upload a file to particular folder in Dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have an iphone app where I want to upload a file on phone's local disk to user's dropbox. I want to give the user an option to upload it to anywhere in his dropbox. I have seen many apps do this but haven't found any example online that takes me through a step by step tutorial. Any pointers will be helpful!

EDIT :

```
//setup
 DBSession* dbSession = [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:@"XXX"
                                                 appSecret:@"XXX"
                                                      root:kDBRootDropbox];
  [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
  [self handleDropboxSession];

  DBRestClient *restclient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:dbSession];
  restclient.delegate = self;

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f block:^{
    [self testSaveFileToDBox:restclient];
  } repeats:NO];



//relevant methods
-(void)testSaveFileToDBox:(DBRestClient *)client
{
  NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
  NSString *filename = @"working-draft.txt";
  NSString *destDir = @"/";
  [client uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                  withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

  NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
  NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);
}

-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath{
  NSLog(@"upload progress");
}
```

The file "working-draft.txt" does not exist but then the error delegate method is not getting called. FWIW, this all is in app delegate.

Comment: Show your relevant code where you make an effort to upload a file to Dropbox.

Comment: @rmaddy edited with code sample

Comment: BTW, I found https://github.com/goosoftware/GSDropboxActivity which is pretty similar. If you know if there's anything better, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest thing is https://github.com/goosoftware/GSDropboxActivity. It seems dropbox does not provide an official "folder chooser" so all these apps are rolling out their own custom solution like the one I show above.